# Chaining .bind() calls in JavaScript. Unexpected result?

Tags: javascript

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value

And I can happily see it working in this example:

```
(function () {
   console.log(this);
}).bind({foo:"bar"})();
```

which logs `Object { foo="bar"}`.

But if I chain another bind call, or even a "call" call, I'm still getting the function invoked with "this" assigned to the object passed to the first bind.  Examples:

```
(function () {
   console.log(this);
}).bind({foo:"bar"}).bind({oof:"rab"})();
```

&

```
(function () {
   console.log(this);
}).bind({foo:"bar"}).call({oof:"rab"});
```

Both log `Object { foo="bar"}` instead of what I would expect: `Object { oof="rab"}`.

No matter how many bind calls I chain, only the first one seems to have an effect.

**Why?**

This might help. I just found out jQuery's version is behaving the same way! :O

```
jQuery.proxy(
  jQuery.proxy(function() {
      console.log(this);
  },{foo:"bar"})
,{oof:"rab"})();
```

logs `Object { foo="bar"}`

Comment: Weird! Good question

Comment: The ecma website is down... Does anyone know a mirror to the Web ECMAScript spec?

Comment: Great question. So good, in fact, it's knocked the ES5 spec offline. I think you've broken JavaScript.

Comment: @joews seems fair, Javascript's broken me a few times too ! haha

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20141020103516/http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: what might the use of chaining bind() be?

Comment: @tomasb It came up by using the observer pattern. The function I attached was the result of a bind call, and in the "observable" notify method I was using "call" to execute that function. I just wanted to make sure the first value was preserved and then this question came to my mind.

Comment: This also doesn't do a proper bind: `Function.prototype.bind.call(function() { console.log(this) }, {foo:'bar'})`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is tempting to think of `bind` as somehow *modifying* a function to use a new `this`. In this (incorrect) interpretation, people think of `bind` as adding some kind of magic flag to the function telling it to use a different `this` next time it's called. If that were the case, then it should be possible to "override" and change the magic flag. And one would then ask, what is the reason for arbitrarily restricting the ability to do so?

But in fact, that's **not** how it works. **`bind` creates and returns a *new* function** which when called invokes the first function with a particular `this`. The behavior of this newly created function, to use the specified `this` to call the original function, is **burned in** when the function is created. It cannot be changed any more than the internals of any other function returned by a function could be changed after the fact.

It may help to look at a real simple implementation of `bind`:

```
// NOT the real bind; just an example
Function.prototype.bind = function(ctxt) {
    var fn = this;
    return function bound_fn() {
        return fn.apply(ctxt, arguments);
    };
}

my_bound_fn = original_fn.bind(obj);
```

As you can see, nowhere in `bound_fn`, the function returned from `bind`, does it refer to the `this` with which the bound function was called. It's ignored, so that

```
my_bound_fn.call(999, arg)            // 999 is ignored
```

or

```
obj = { fn: function () { console.log(this); } };
obj.fn = obj.fn.bind(other_obj);
obj.fn();                            // outputs other_obj; obj is ignored
```

So I can bind the function returned from `bind` "again", but that is **not** rebinding the original function; it's merely binding the outer function, which has no effect on the inner function, since it is already set up to call the underlying function with the context (`this` value) passed to `bind`. I can bind again and again but all I end up doing is creating more outer functions which may be bound to something but still end up calling the innermost function returned from the first `bind`.

Therefore, it is somewhat misleading to say that `bind` "cannot be overridden".

If I want to "rebind" a function, then I can just do a new binding on the original function. So if I've bound it once:

```
function orig() { }
my_bound_fn = orig.bind(my_obj);
```

and then I want to arrange for my original function to be called with some other `this`, then I don't rebind the bound function:

```
my_bound_fn = my_bound_fn.bind(my_other_obj);     // No effect
```

Instead, I just create a new function bound to the original one:

```
my_other_bound_fn = orig.bind(my_other_obj);
```

Comment: Super great! Why there is no such explanation in docs??

Answer (score 14):

I found this line on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the
>   same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as
>   the function it is being called on (the bound function's target
>   function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(),
>   **which cannot be overridden.**

so maybe it's really cannot be overridden once it is set.

Comment: Would it be too cheeky to ask why it cannot be overriden?

Comment: that's something i don't know, and i hope some wise person will bring light on this

Answer (score 5):

torazaburo's excellent answer gave me an idea. It would be possible for a bind-like function, instead of baking the receiver (this) into the call inside a closure, to put it as a property on the function object and then use it when the call is made. That would allow a rebind to update the property before the call is made, effectively giving the rebind results that you expected.

For example,

```js
function original_fn() {
    document.writeln(JSON.stringify(this));
}

Function.prototype.rebind = function(obj) {
    var fn = this;
    var bound = function func() {
        fn.call(func.receiver, arguments);
    };
    bound.receiver = obj;
    bound.rebind = function(obj) {
        this.receiver = obj;
        return this;
    };
    return bound;
}

var bound_fn = original_fn.rebind({foo: 'bar'});

bound_fn();

var rebound_fn = bound_fn.rebind({fred: 'barney'});

rebound_fn();
```

Or, the output from node.js is as follows.

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
{ fred: 'barney' }
```

Note that the first call to `rebind` is calling the one that was added to `Function.prototype` since it is being called on ordinary function `original_fn`, but the second call is calling the `rebind` that was added as a property to the bound function (and any subsequent calls will call this one, as well). That `rebind` simply updates `receiver` and returns the same function object.

It was possible to access the `receiver` property within the bound function by making it a *named function expression*.

Comment: @torazaburo Unfortunately, `document.writeln` doesn't have the ability to format objects nicely. Replacing `console.log` with `document.writeln` just produces `[Object object]` as output.

Comment: Uhh, `document.writeln(JSON.stringify(boo))`?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is going to be mostly speculation but I'll try and reason through it.

The ECMAScript specification (which is currently down) states the following for the `bind` function (emphasis my own):

> 15.3.4.5 Function.prototype.bind (thisArg [, arg1 [, arg2, …]])
>
> The bind method takes one or more arguments, thisArg and (optionally)
>   arg1, arg2, etc, and returns a new  function object by performing the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. **Let Target be the this value.**
> 2. If IsCallable(Target) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 3. Let A be a new (possibly empty) internal list of all of the argument values provided after thisArg (arg1, arg2 etc), in order.
> 4. **Let F be a new native ECMAScript object** .
> 5. Set all the internal methods, except for [[Get]], of F as specified in 8.12.
> 6. Set the [[Get]] internal property of F as specified in 15.3.5.4.
> 7. ***Set the [[TargetFunction]] internal property of F to Target.***
> 8. Set the [[BoundThis]] internal property of F to the value of thisArg.
> 9. Set the [[BoundArgs]] internal property of F to A.
> 10. Set the [[Class]] internal property of F to "Function".
> 11. Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of F to the standard built-in Function prototype object as specified in 
>       15.3.3.1.
> 12. Set the [[Call]] internal property of F as described in 15.3.4.5.1.
> 13. Set the [[Construct]] internal property of F as described in 15.3.4.5.2.
> 14. Set the [[HasInstance]] internal property of F as described in 15.3.4.5.3.
> 15. If the [[Class]] internal property of Target is "Function", then a. Let L be the length property of Target minus the length of A. b.
>       Set the length own property of F to either 0 or L, whichever is
>       larger.
> 16. Else set the length own property of F to 0.
> 17. Set the attributes of the length own property of F to the values specified in 15.3.5.1.
> 18. Set the [[Extensible]] internal property of F to true.
> 19. Let thrower be the [[ThrowTypeError]] function Object (13.2.3).
> 20. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of F with arguments "caller", PropertyDescriptor  {[[Get]]: thrower, [[Set]]: thrower,
>       [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false}, and false.
> 21. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of F with arguments "arguments", PropertyDescriptor  {[[Get]]: thrower, [[Set]]: thrower,
>       [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false}, and false.
> 22. Return F

And when you call a `function` on your Object that was created with `bind`:

> 15.3.4.5.1 [[Call]]
>
> When the [[Call]] internal method of a function object, F, which was created using the bind function is called  with a
>   this value and a list of arguments ExtraArgs, the following steps are
>   taken:
>
> 1. Let boundArgs be the value of F’s [[BoundArgs]] internal property.
> 2. Let boundThis be the value of F’s [[BoundThis]] internal property.
> 3. ***Let target be the value of F’s [[TargetFunction]] internal property.***
> 4. Let args be a new list containing the same values as the list boundArgs in the same order followed by the  same values as the list
>      ExtraArgs in the same order.
> 5. ***Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of target providing boundThis as the this value and  providing args as the
>      arguments***

Call specifies how every function is called. And somewhat resembles the JavaScript `call`:

```
someFunction.[[call]](thisValue, arguments) {

}
```

However when `[[call]]` is used on a bound function, the `thisValue` is overridden with the value of `[[BoundThis]]`. In the case of calling `bind` a second time, the `thisValue` that you attempt to override the first with is replaced by `[[BoundThis]]`, essentially incurring no effect whatsoever on the value of `thisValue`:

```
boundFunction.[[call]](thisValue, arguments) {
  thisValue = boundFunction.[[BoundThis]];
}
```

You'll notice that if you try and use `call` or `apply` then they will also have no effect because their attempt to override the `thisValue` property will be reversed when `[[call]]` invokes the next function.

Answer (score 0):

These simplified examples of how `bind()` works explain it better.

Here is what function bound once looks like:

```
function bound_function() {

    function original_function() {
        console.log(self);
    }

    var self = 1;
    original_function();
}

bound_function()
```

Here is what happens if we wrap original function twice:

```
function bound_function2() {

    function bound_function1() {

        function original_function() {
            console.log(self);
        }

        var self = 1;
        original_function();
    }

    var self = 2;
    bound_function1();
}

bound_function2()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to think about it is: When you call bind() the first time the value of 'this' inside the function returned by the call to bind() is FIXED, to the given value. That is possible BECAUSE it wasn't fixed before, it was unbound.  But once it is fixed it can not be fixed to anything else because it is no longer unfixed, it is no longer a "variable".

In theory there could be an opposite operation to bind called "unbind" which you could call like:

```
myFunk.bind(something)
      .unbind(); // -> has same behavior as original myFunk
```

The name "bind" indicates that the (pseudo-) variable 'this' is BOUND to something, it is not simply ASSIGNED a value, which could then be assigned again and again.

When something is "bound" it has a value and that value can not be replaced --because it is "bound". So you would need an unbind() operation to make that possible. But since you assumably have the original function around somewhere
there is no need for "unbind" really.

I agree this behavior is perhaps surprising and unexpected and thus possibly error-prone because if you get a function as argument there seems to be no way to tell whether your bind() on it has any effect or not.

HOWEVER if you don't know much about such function-argument it would also be impossible to know what kind of value you CAN bind to it without breaking the calls it makes to 'this' inside it.

SO the bind() operation itself is rather hazardous. Re-binding would be doubly hazardous. So you are best off trying to avoid doing that if possible.