# Why we cannot access the 'this' inside the inner function?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, there are two functions, the outer function, and the inner IIFE function.

The output for the code below is:

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

I do not understand why in the inner IIFE function, `this` cannot be used to access the foo variable while `self` still can. I understand that `var self` is a global varible for the inner function and can still be accessed. But what about `this` ?

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Comment: To keep the same `this` through function closures you can use `(function(){}).bind(this)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the inner function, `this` *can* be referenced, but it has a *different value* than in the outer function. Every function call involves setting up `this` for that particular call inside the called function. Note that it's every function **call** that determines `this`; it's not about the inherent nature of the function, it's about how a function is called.

In this case, the anonymous inner function is called without any explicit value for `this`, so its value will be a reference to the global object (`window` in a browser). In "strict" mode, the value would be `undefined`.

You could force `this` to be `self`:

```
    (function() {
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    }.call(self));
```

By using `.call()`, the explicit value for `this` inside the anonymous function assures that it will reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Every function can have a different value of `this`, regardless of nesting, when it ends up being called. That is unless the function has been previously bound, which sets `this` to a particular value. In this case, the inner function is not part of a prototype, not called or bound to an object, so `this` will default back to `window` (or more correctly termed `self`).

You can resolve that in a few ways:

1. Call the inner function with a scope, using `}.call(this)` instead of `}()`. This will explicitly provide the scope you want.
2. Use closure to capture `self` (poorly named, since there is [a global property with the same name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)) and use that in place of `this`.

Comment: This is confused on a number of levels. A function does not "have its own this". `this` attaches to an **invocation** of a function, not the function itself. A function cannot "be previously bound"; I guess you are referring to the act of creating a new function which calls an original function with a particular `this`.

Comment: @torazaburo The first part could use some clarification: every function, when invoked, can have a different value for `this` regardless of nesting. However, on the second point, a function absolutely *can* be previously bound. What do you think `bind` returns? It's a function that has been bound to a particular value of `this` at some point in the past and can be reused.

Comment: @ssube  `.bind()` returns a *new function* - the original function isn't changed. That new function can itself be invoked with any value for `this`; it just happens to ignore it.

Comment: @ssube Well, actually not. It is not correct to say "the function returned by `bind` is bound to a particular value of `this`, unless one is using the term "bind" loosely. What `bind` does is to return a function whose inner logic is to invoke an original function with a particular `this`. There is no formal notion of a "bound function". For instance, functions have no field or something which specifies some binding. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545549/chaining-bind-calls-in-javascript-unexpected-result/26547029#26547029.