# In JavaScript, the first bind determines who "this" is? (Binding it twice or a second time doesn't matter)

Tags: javascript, bind

If `bind(obj)` can return a function with `this` bound to `obj`, then wouldn't

```
fn.bind(obj1).bind(obj2)
```

return a function with `this` bound to `obj2`?

It looks like only the first bind will bind it, regardless of the second bind, or if we bind it twice or more?  Is that part of the specs?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hah0L3nj/

```
var obj1 = { name: "Mike" },
    obj2 = { name: "Mary" };

console.log(obj1, obj2);

function printName() {
    console.log(this.name);
}

printName.bind(obj1)();
printName.bind(obj2)();

printName.bind(obj1).bind(obj2)();
```

The last line will print "Mike".

I think the reason is that `bind` is implemented like this:

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function (obj) {
    var self = this;
    return function () {
        self.call(obj);
    }
};
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/hah0L3nj/1/

So what is done is a tight bound, and any outer bound (extra wrapping) won't really matter.  But I wonder if other implementation of `bind` can do otherwise, and what the spec says.

Comment: `printName` is not called at second `.bind()`

Comment: This is because you're not binding `printName` within the chain of `bind`s, you're binding the `bind()` function instead.

Comment: @ryeballar what do you mean, so what if I bind it in 2 steps: http://jsfiddle.net/hah0L3nj/2/  that I do  `var printName2 = printName.bind(obj1);`
`var printName3 = printName2.bind(obj2);`
`printName3();`

Comment: @torazaburo Should post approach for solution to this specific Question - referencing this Question - that does not create different `.bind()` functionality , at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545549/chaining-bind-calls-in-javascript-unexpected-result ? Possibly more than one approach to return expected results

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @torazaburo _"What is the expected result?"_ Appear for `this` to be `obj2` at `printName.bind(obj1).bind(obj2)();` ? If yes , could substitute chaining `.bind()` for passing second object as parameter to `.bind()` ; using `arguments.callee.name` within `printName` to bind second object to `printName` - if argument passed `this` remains set to initial bound object , logs `"Mike"` , else logs `"Mary"`  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33832974/

Comment: That's not bind, it's something else. You can write anything you want to do anything you want, but bind, by its intrinsic nature, cannot accomplish this.

Comment: @torazaburo _"That's not bind, it's something else"_ ? What is "not bind" ?

Comment: @guest271314 I mean, `bind` is `bind`. By its nature, binding an already bound function is not going to do anything. This is JavaScript, so you could invent any amount of machinery to do other/different binding-like things, but they are not bind, even if you call it bind.

Comment: @torazaburo Only described potential approach of using parameters option available at `.bind(this, parameters)` to pass second object ; if arguments found in bound initial function , call `.bind()` on object in arguments to initial function .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can say function.bind() does *not modify* the function itself. Instead, it creates a new function, a wrapper, that, when called, ensures the bound function always get the same context. Unless you store the result of bind() in a variable, it has no effect.