# How to inspect a JavaScript Bound Function

Tags: javascript

is there any way to inspect a JavaScript bound function?

I want to return a bound function from a function, and in unit testing, to assert the bound function's target, boundThis, and boundArgs. They seem to be defined as internal object in ECMAScript and cannot be accessed in program.

Is there any way to access them? or maybe some people with similar requirements have already written some module patching Function.prototype.bind()?

Comment: FWIW... in unit tests you usually want to test *what a piece of code does*, not *how* it does it. The "what" is the test, the "how" is the implementation. This seems like the wrong thing to focus on in a unit test.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545549/chaining-bind-calls-in-javascript-unexpected-result/26547029#26547029. The `this` used when a bound function is called is not some kind of hidden property on the function. It is part of the logic used to wrap the original function to create the bound function. You cannot inspect that any more than you could inspect a local variable in a function or any other logic internal to a function, and as @Bergi rightly points out, you don't want to and shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not (unless you fire up a debugger).

You should not test for bound functions anyway. You could achieve the exact same behaviour with a closure as well, which would not expose the closed-over variables either. And it doesn't matter. You should not test the implementation, but the behaviour - so just check whether calling the returned function does invoke the target with the expected values.

Comment: But I definitely disagree with you on that bound functions should not be tested. Nowadays, ES6 promise are frequently used. Many functions return promises. But promise is an opaque object, no way to check what a promise is, there is no method to do equality check by value. A better way is to return a bound function, if it could be inspected. It is much better than resolving the promise and assert the result since the promise probably has side effect. Keeping the tested function 'pure' is the key to the problem.

Comment: Promise is something like the monad in Haskell, in the sense that it contains a value. But itself is not a value. This is a problem. and functions return it can NOT be pure. A workaround solution is using an object representing a bound function as the return value instead of promise. It can be converted to a promise with no ambiguity. Then this object can be directly asserted, rather than resolving the promise. Functions return such object can be pure.

Comment: Furthermore, supposing such adapter function is named as M(). It accepts an object representing a bound function and returns a promise, then in Promise/then/catch chain. all pure functions are wrapped by M function and then pass to then or catch. Another benefit in this approach is, if you want to test code coverage, you dont need to mock any side-effect function inside promise, all you need to do is to change the behavior of M function, inspecting the input and output the testdata as result. I can't say promise is bad, but it only walked half way towards functional programming.

Comment: Yes, the promise type is a `Monad`. But that doesn't make it impure or even guarantee side effects. Yes, you cannot define `Eq` on it (disregarding object identity), but actually, you cannot do the same on functions either. A "bound function" (whatever exactly that is) that has a 1:1 correspondence to promises is equal to promises for all purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an IO monad implementation that not only wraps asynchrony (like promises do) but also side effects. There certainly are libraries for that, but actually your monadic function composition will just stay function composition, producing opaque function objects. The only way you can test functions for equality is by running them. The only thing that changes from the `Promise` to such an `IO` monad is that you can contain (and mock) side effects.

Comment: In most cases, a promise wraps a (possibly and probably) anonymous function, but if we give that function a name, we can separate the pure function and the impure function. In many cases, the impure one is from node.js or third party libraries, which we don't want to test. Then we can test the pure part only. I consider it a huge benefit in testing over asserting the resolved value from impure, runtime or third-party library functions.