# Why does not .bind() rewrite working?

Tags: javascript, bind

Please, review the following code:

```
function func() {
    console.log(this.name);
}
console.log(
    func.bind({name: 99}) // first bind
        .bind({name: 1})  // second bind
        ()                // execution
);
```

The result:

```
99
undefined
```

1. Why is `undefined` showing? (I expected a single result)
2. Why did `.bind()` not rewrite the context?
3. Is this code equivalent?

   ```
   function ff() {
       return function () {
           return function () {            
               return func.apply({name: 99});
           }.apply({name: 2})
       }
   }
   console.log(ff()());
   ```

Comment: `func()` calls `console.log()`, then returns `undefined`, and you call `console.log()` again on that.

Comment: Binding a function twice will do nothing. Once it is bound, the context is "burnt" in.

Comment: @torazaburo just by design ?

Comment: By the nature of bind. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545549/chaining-bind-calls-in-javascript-unexpected-result/26547029#26547029.