# Use bind function twice

Tags: javascript, bind

In the 
[MDN][bind]

We see this code like this

```
this.x = 9;    // this refers to global "window" object here in the browser
var module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() { return this.x; }
};
module.getX(); // 81
var retrieveX = module.getX;
retrieveX();   
// returns 9 - The function gets invoked at the global scope
var boundGetX = retrieveX.bind(module);
boundGetX();
```

YES，I know the bind will change the "this" value,But I confuse a code below

```
var demo=boundGetX.bind(this);// or boundGetX.bind(window);
demo();// still 81
```

Use bind again and I think it will change "this" point to "window",but it is not .
I wonder why.

Comment: `boundGetX` will be a function that calls `retrieveX` on module regardless what `this` value it receives. Now if you `bind` that again, the `window` will be exactly that: disregarded.

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this, right? Anyone?

Comment: @Bergi check out this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545549/chaining-bind-calls-in-javascript-unexpected-result

Comment: @SkuraZZ Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`bind` *returns a new function* which keeps the context of the original function intact when called. In essence it does this:

```
function bind(originalFunction, context) {
    return function () {
        originalFunction.call(context);
    };
}
```

No matter how you call that bound function or what else you do to it, `originalFunction` will be called with a specific context. You can rebind that bound function which will return yet another new function, but that doesn't influence the "inner wrapped" original function and context.