# How to override `this` value for the already bound function using bind method

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code. Here `getGreeting` is already bound with `Salutation`.When the `getGreeting` is bound with `myName` using `bind()`, it still called with context of `Salutation` class.

```
let myName = {
  name: 'John'
}
class Salutation {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Mike';
        this.getGreeting = this.getGreeting.bind(this)
    }
    getGreeting() {
      return `Hi. My name is ${this.name}`
    }
}
const salutation = new Salutation();
console.log(salutation);

boundFunction = salutation.getGreeting.bind(this);
boundFunction();// My name is Mike

boundFunction = salutation.getGreeting.bind(myName);
boundFunction();// My name is Mike
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining .bind() calls in JavaScript. Unexpected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545549/chaining-bind-calls-in-javascript-unexpected-result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

`bind` creates a *new function* (B) which calls the original function (A) with a particular `this`.

Trying to rebind it creates another new function (C) which calls the previous function (B) with a particular `this`. B, however, doesn't care what the value of `this` is, it still calls A with the value it was originally told to use.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I got working is to play with a context, inside the class itself :

```js
const myName = {
  name: 'John'
};

class Salutation {
    constructor() {
       this.name = 'Mike';
       
       this.tmpContext = this;
    }
    
    getGreeting() {
      const func = function() {
         return `Hi. My name is ${this.name}`;
      }.bind(this.tmpContext);
      
      return func();
    }
}

const salutation = new Salutation();

salutation.tmpContext = myName;

console.log(salutation.getGreeting());

salutation.tmpContext = salutation;

console.log(salutation.getGreeting());
```